# For RESTful API, how to create for many to many relationship

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

There are two entities(Club and User), and their realtion table(ClubUser)。

- Club

  - id
  - name
- User

  - id
  - name
- ClubUser

  - club_id
  - user_id

Now, when we create a club for POST /clubs，we want to create several ClubUsers. What is the pest practice?

I can find these 3 solutions.

1. Request once

Request url: `/clubs`

Request method: `POST`

Request body:

```
{
  name: 'club name',
  users: [
    {
       id: 1
    },
    {
       id: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

---

2. Request twice

Request1 url: `/clubs`

Request1 method: `POST`

Request1 body:

```
{
  name: 'club name'
}
```

Request2 url: `/clubs/1/users`

Request2 method: `POST`

Request2 body:

```
[
  {
     user_id: 1
  },
  {
     user_id: 2
  }
]
```

---

3. request multiple times

Request1 url: `/clubs`

Request1 method: `POST`

Request1 body:

```
{
  name: 'club name'
}
```

Request2 url: `/clubs/1/users/1`

Request2 method: `POST`

Request3 url: `/clubs/1/users/2`

Request3 method: `POST`

---

The third one may look nice, but it requests multiple times.

What is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: What is good for your situation depends mainly on the context. Try to implement one and look if it fits you. Will you create 10.000 clubs at once for example. In that case solution 3 is not very wise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Models

```
from django.db.models import (
    Model, ManyToManyField
)
class User(Model):
    club = ManyToManyField(Club)
```

> Serializers

```
from rest_framework.serializers import (
    ModelSerializer, IntegerField, RelatedField
)
class ClubRelatedField(RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = {
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name
        }
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, id):
        return Club.objects.get(id=id)

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    club = ClubRelatedField(
        queryset=Club.objects.all(), many=True, required=True
    )
```